# More examples of maximal non-normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm looking for examples of maximal non-normal subgroups. From another post I found the example of {(1), (12)} in $S_3$ but would like some more to help get my mind around the concept. Anyone have more examples?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, in a simple group all proper subgroups are nonnormal. The smallest simple group with proper subgroups is $A_5$, which has order $60$, and up to conjugacy it has three maximal subgroups:

- $\langle (123), (12)(45) \rangle \cong S_3$
- $\langle (12345), (15)(24) \rangle \cong D_{10}$
- $\langle (123), (12)(34)\rangle \cong A_4$

Since $[A_5 : A_4] = 5$ is prime, we can see immediately that $A_4$ is maximal; showing maximality in the other two cases takes a little more work.

Answer (score 2):

An important example in the study of Lie groups is the *special linear group* $$SL(2, \Bbb R) := \{A \in M(2, \Bbb R) : \det A = 1\},$$ together with any of its Borel subgroups, all of which are conjugate to one another, and one of which is the subgroup $$\left\{\pmatrix{a&b\\&a^{-1}} : a \in \Bbb R^*, b \in \Bbb R\right\}$$of upper-triangular matrices in $SL(2, \Bbb R)$.